# Enable text hovering cursor when textbox is empty

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, cursor

I have some TextBox, when I hover my mouse over it, the cursor does not change:

[image: Empty TextBox]

However, when I enter some text, I do see a cursor when hovering:

[image: Non-empty TextBox]

I want the cursor to be visible in this text mode even when the textbox is empty.

Comment: is it default `TextBox` template?

Comment: @dkozl Yes, though it inherits style from its parent

Comment: Default WPF template seems to work as you expect; you can see that cursor over whole `TextBox` whether you've entered text or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior displays the I Beam when you mouse over a textbox, I'm unsure what is going on with your textbox, you may be overriding this behavior in a style.

You could implement this trigger to get around it:

```
<TextBox>
   <TextBox.Style>
      <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="IBeam"/>
            </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
     </TextBox.Style>
   </TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here because I had changed the cursor in my ViewModel with:

```
Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Arrow;
```

The correct way to set the cursor to default behavior is:

```
Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
```